# Reset my network, sharing and network security settings on Windows 8

Tags: networking, windows-8

Is it possible to do? Somewhere I have an setting or something which is prohibiting other PC's on the network from authenticating a shared connection (File and printer sharing) and I have gone through each setting and cannot find it.

Is it possible to reset all of my network settings to default/factory without formatting or reinstalling my pc?